# how to add a href link in a variable in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have created a variable inside a controller whereby I want to put a href link inside the variable. everything works well but I want to add a download link for the to be able to view the link in the message sent to them.I have tried this but the URL isn't being rendered in the message.I haven't understood where am doing it wrong.

```
 $downloadurl="'downloadpaymentreceipt/$payment->id/$payment->date_paid'";

        // Set your message
$message = "hello there your payment has been received.Click <a href=$downloadurl>Here</a> to downoad your receipt.";
```

Comment: What do you mean "_the URL isn't being rendered_"? Do you mean the value of `$downloadurl` is not correct, or a link in your view is not being rendered?

Comment: @Peppermintology the link in the view is not being rendered..i want to make the link clickable in the view

Comment: How are you outputting `$message` in your view?

Comment: its an sms that is being sent in the users phone

Comment: @stephenWeru `SMS` messages are text based format messages that do not support `HTML`. You may just write the URL directly in your message and most phones (smartphones especially) will highlight the link for the user. Keep in mind that `SMS` length, in terms of chars, should not exceed `160` (technically) and thus i recommend you *shorten* your URL before putting it in the SMS because URLs tend to be long.

Comment: @ths my url link is downloadpaymentreceipt/$payment->id/$payment->date_paid  i want to append the link and make it clickable

Comment: As @ths mentioned, SMS messages don't support HTML. They do however recognise URLs so rather than using `click here` you can instead provide the full `URL` or a shortened link and the mobile device _should_ recognise it and link it.

Comment: @stephenWeru you have to write the full URL in order to support all the SMS apps/readers out there. I mentioned that SMS message have a limit and gave you possible workaround by using a shortened URL. There are many packages that could help you shorten an URL in `Laravel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$message = 'hello there your payment has been received.Click <a 
     href="' . $downloadurl . '">Here</a> to downoad your receipt.";
```

Or like this

```
$message = "<p>hello there your payment has been received.Click <a 
   href='{$downloadurl}'>Here</a> to downoad your receipt.</p>";
```

Answer (score -1):

use the back cotes (``)

```html
$message = "hello there your payment has been received.Click `<a href=$downloadurl>Here</a>` to downoad your receipt.";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What do you mean by "back cotes", and how does that resolve the given problem?

Comment: Please solely use english in the comment section, such that other users can understand your comments